# Most efficient way to create multidimensional array of same chars? [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, multidimensional-array, repeat

sorry if this has been answered somewhere else. I am pretty new and do not know how to really explain a question like this.

Right now, I'm seeking to create a [5]x[5] array all of the '+' character. Here's what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
char map[5][5] = {{'+','+','+','+','+'},{'+','+','+','+','+'},{'+','+','+','+','+'},{'+','+','+','+','+'},{'+','+','+','+','+'}};

for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++) 
        cout << map[x][y] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to repeat those '+' chars without having to list each one out over and over?

Thank you :)

In the long run, I'm looking to create an [n]x[n] map that a player can walk around and interact in as a fun learning project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it is pretty straightforward: just do a simple loop:

```
char map[5][5];
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++) 
        map[x][y]='+';
}
```

Comment: appreciate it :) Thanks everyone else as well

Answer (score 2):

If you want the least possible code, how about:

```
#include <string.h>
memset(&map[0][0], 'x', sizeof(map));
```

Comment: Why not just `memset(map, 'x', sizeof(map));`?

Comment: @BillLynch I believe `memset` wants a pointer and not a double pointer so you would have to at least put something like `map[0]`

Comment: @meneldal `map` can be implicitly converted to `char(*)[5]` with a value still pointing to `map[0][0]`. So I think it should work.

Comment: I thought the thing that differentiated C++ from C was that there was a consensus that implicit pointers conversions were evil. The idiomatic C++ for this problem would use a `std::vector` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The constructors of `std::vector` provide an easy way to, well, construct the object easily:

```
#include <vector>
//...
std::size_t n = 5;
std::vector<std::vector<char>> map(std::vector<char>('+', n), n);
//If using Visual Studio 2012 (or equivalent) or earlier:
std::vector<std::vector<char> > map(std::vector<char>('+', n), n);
```

Comment: You should always use the second one to be safe and this is not a Visual Studio thing, it's only in the C++11 standard.

Comment: @meneldal Hence the "or equivalent" :P